# Как намеренно испортить качество фотографии Python?

Tags: python, pillow

Знаю про библиотеку Pillow, с аргументом quality = 1, но качество изображения все равно выходит не настолько ужасной, как хотелось бы. Есть ли другие варианты, библиотеки, что бы качество фото вышло приблизительно такое?:

[image: Ужасное качество]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть решения, которые частично решают вашу проблему пользуясь всё той же библиотекой Pillow
Использование Мозайки и Мозайки с блюром:

Мозайка:

```
img.resize([x // 8 for x in img.size]).resize(img.size)
```

Мозайка с блюром:

```
your_img = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(4))
your_img.resize([x // 8 for x in img.size]).resize(img.size)
```